# Need of multiple Routes in Asp.net MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

What is the actual need for multiple routes in an Asp.net MVC application?
We can done all using the default route

Comment: Obviously, if in your particular scenario all can be done using only one default route - you don't need any additional ones. In most cases default route is enough. But sometimes things can be more complicated.

Comment: i am child in MVC, can u provide simple example for the usage of multiple routes?

Comment: Have a look to official [MVC tutorial](http://www.asp.net/mvc/overview/older-versions-1/controllers-and-routing/creating-custom-routes-cs). It describes scenario when you might need multiple routes.

Comment: What is your need ? Multiple routes can be done by attribute or adding to route tables. Can you provide more details ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one scenario when you want to provide user friendly URLs instead of action names like below -

```
public class CustomersController : controller
{
    public ActionResult GetCustomers(string name)
   {
     //Implementation
   }
}
```

For the above action, you can define the route as below -

```
routes.MapRoute(
            "CustSearch",                                              
            "Customers/SearchByName/{id}",                           
            new { controller = "Customers", action = "GetCustomers", id = "" }  
        );
```